# Meteor.call and Meteor.methods not working on mobile (iOS) but perfectly works on web and iOS simulator

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-methods

Not exactly sure how to put this but Meteor.call and .methods are not working when building the app on the mobile specifically on iOS although I haven't tried yet on Android. On my previous project, this doesn't happen. I tried comparing with the other app and, actually, I reused the other for this new app but it just doesn't work. Also, everything works perfectly fine on both web and iOS simulator. Someone please help.

imports/startup/server/methods.js

```
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.methods({

    methodTrial: function(data) {
        console.log("Called methodTrial");
        return false;
    }

});
```

imports/startup/ui/pages/home.js

```
import './home.html';

import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Template.payment.events({
    "click #test-method": (event) => {
        var data = {
            name : "Hello World"
        };
        Meteor.call('methodTrial', data, (error, result) => {
            console.log("Called 'methodTrial'");
        }
    }
});
```

imports/startup/server/index.js

```
import './methods.js';
```

server/main.js

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

import '/imports/startup/server';
```

Comment: Are you running on device as debug? (i.e. `meteor run ios-device`) If so, have you checked that your device can connect to your local server through WiFi?

Comment: @ghybs Hmm I'm not sure on the "debug" but yes I'm running it via ios-device. I am sure that both devices are connected on the same network and connects on the right ip address. It wouldnt've worked on the simulator if it's not working at all.

Comment: The simulator does not have to go through WiFi, whereas your device has to. Might be worth making sure the device can connect to your server with [`Meteor.status()`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html#Meteor-status)

Comment: @ghybs Right, of course. If it cannot connect, then what can I do?

Comment: Have you tried if it is the root cause for your issue?

Comment: @ghybs It is the issue. The app really cannot connect. I forgot to look on this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139149/discussion-between-zangetsu-and-ghybs).

Answer (score 0):

Your `'methodTrial'` Meteor method is server only.

Therefore your client does not run any stub / simulation of that method, and purely relies on the server response to give the user any feedback.

If for any reason the device cannot connect to your server, the client will not be able to trigger the method on the server, and it will never receive any response.

A common misconception during development is that because your device (whether iOS or Android based) is wired to your computer (through USB data cable), it is connected to your server. But actually this is only true for app deployment (when you execute `meteor run ios-device` or `meteor run android-device`). Once the app is installed and open, it needs to connect to your computer local server through your WiFi network.

See the [Meteor Guide > Build > Mobile > Developing on a mobile](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#connecting-to-the-server):

> During development, […] the device and the computer you run `meteor` on will have to be part of the same WiFi network, and the network configuration shouldn’t prevent the device from reaching the server. You may have to change your firewall or router settings to allow for this (no client isolation).
>
> `meteor run` will try to detect the local IP address of the computer running the command automatically. If this fails, or if you would like your mobile app to connect to a different server, you can specify an address using the `--mobile-server` option.

Common mistakes are:

- Not enabling WiFi on device.
- Not allowing the device to connect to the WiFi network (MAC address filtering on router, etc.)
- Not allowing incoming IP requests on the development computer.